# How read the first and the last line of a file in scala

Tags: scala, file

I am reading a file that contain the following:

```
16,44,34
16,47,18
22,44,28
22,47,24
```

but I just want to read the first and the last line of the file, 
In this moment I am reading the file as an Iterator:

```
 while (in2.hasNext) {
        val s  = in2.next(',').toInt
        val p = in2.next(',').toInt
        val o  = in2.next('\n').toInt
 }
```

but I am reading the whole file, exist a way in scala to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can write it a little nicer, and save on not having to parse every line in the file, but you will still have to *read* them all, unless you are willing to do some acrobatics with random access files and binary data (probably, not worth the effort, unless the file is truly *huge*).

```
   val lines = Source.fromFile("input_file.csv").getLines
   val firstLine = if(lines.hasNext) Some(lines.next) else None
   val lastLine = lines.foldLeft(Option.empty[String]) { case (_, line) => Some(line) }
   val spos: Seq[Seq[Int]] = (firstLine ++ lastLine).map(_.split(",").map(_.toInt))

   // next line will fail if there are fewer than two lines in the file
   // or if either first or last line doesn't have exactly three comma-separated fields
   // I am just putting it here to illustrate how you could extract the parsed data

   val Seq(Seq(s1, p1, o1), Seq(s2, p2, o2)) = spos
```

**Update**

Ok, if you really don't want to have to read through the entire file, you can try something like this (this is a crude approach, based on the fact that your lines are all short, so I can be sure that if I land somewhere ~1000 bytes from the end of the file, I'll definitely be well before the start of the last line.

```
   val file = new RandomAccessFile("input_file.csv", "r")
   val firstLine = Option(file.readLine)
   if(file.length > 1024 + firstLine.fold(0)(_.length))
      file.skipBytes(file.length - 1024)
   val lastLine = Iterator.continually(file.readLine)
     .takeWhile(_ != null)
     .foldLeft(Option.empty[String]) { case (_, line) => line }
```

(the rest of the earlier snippet can stay the same).

Comment: Yes, it is ok, but indeed I want to do some acrobatics with random access files and binary data, becuase the file has 277000 lines...

Comment: @Vlad ok, I added the random access to the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: BTW, 277000 fairly short lines like yours, doesn't sound that bad actually. If you did read them all, that would be about 2.5 meg of data. With a decent hard drive, it should be maybe 0.05 seconds or so ...